# How to limit user request to Parse in iOS?

Tags: ios, database, request, parse-platform

I am developing an app in iOS that allow user to retrieve data from server. This app is only allow users to get the data from server and save to local, they can not delete or update data. So each day i will update my data and allow user to request to server to get new data. I decide to use Parse but the problem is Parse only allow 1 million request per month, therefore i want to limit the users request. I want to allow them to request 2 times per day only. Is there any way to implement this thing?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ignore my answer, I didn't realize you were on ios. Maybe it will still help.

Comment: Never mind, at least i have some idea to do, thanks for your help :)

Comment: try this link for ios's way of `savedInstanceState`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html

Comment: Is there any other answer ?

Comment: Sorry, that is the only way to do it that I know of.

Comment: Because it is different in IOS :( I'm still "stackoverflow".

Comment: In what sense would you "limit" their requests?  It will only call to Parse, when you as a programmer explicitly call to Parse.  If you "never" call to Parse, it will "never" call to Parse.  If you want to call two times a day, do that. Your question is sort of meaningless! It would be like saying "I want to clap my hands over my head only two times a day. How can I limit it to two times a day?"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Didnt realize it was ios!!

So for Android:
Build a counter that will keep track of how many times they access parse.com

```
 if (i > 2){
     // do not access parse
} else if (i < 2) {
     // access parse
     i++;
}
```

Then you will have to store `i` in `savedInstanceState`.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState .getInt("counter"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}

 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putInt("count", i);
}
```

### IOS's way of [saving/restoring info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)